# Deserialize json string to a class using NewtonSoft.JSON

Tags: c#, json

This is my JSON string

```
{\"currentDateTime\":\"21-09-2014 17:48:00\",\"currentTime\":\"17:48:00.2360971\"}
```

I want to convert it to a class

```
public class CurrentDateTimeJson
    {
        public string currentDateTime { get; set; }
        public string currentTime { get; set; }
    }
```

I am using NewtonSoft.JSON to deserialize.

Following is my code to deserialize

```
var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CurrentDateTimeJson>(jsonString);
```

I am getting following error

**Error converting value "{"currentDateTime":"21-09-2014 17:51:56","currentTime":"17:51:56.9643252"}" to type 'CurrentDateTimeJson'.**

Edit

Code which produces the JSON

```
 public string GetCurrentDateTimeJSON()
        {
            CurrentDateTime cdt = new CurrentDateTime()
            {
                currentDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString(),
                currentTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.ToString()
            };

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cdt);
            return json;
        }
```

Inner Exception

**"Could not cast or convert from System.String to CurrentDateTimeJson."**

Comment: json should be like this: ``{"currentDateTime":"21-09-2014 17:48:00","currentTime":"17:48:00.2360971"}``

Comment: That code works for me - assuming the backslashes are just part of the debugger/source representation, and not in the text itself. Please show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: In the error you are getting, does it contain an InnerException which could suggest what the actual reason could be why it cannot convert?

Comment: Added inner exception and the code which creates JSONstring